# while loop do not execute after for loop

Tags: c

i am learning C programming method and i have a question regarding the loop for an the endentation.
i am using linux debian to compile.

here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char s1[] = "abcdef";
    char s2[] = "aaaaaa";   
    int i, j;

    printf("\ndebut:%s\n", s1);

    for (i = j = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++j){
        if (s1[i] == s2[j]){
            printf("before %c\n", s1[i]);
            s1[i] = '\0';
        }   
        else if (s1[i] != s2[j]){
            s1[i] = s1[i];
            printf("after copy %c\n", s1[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nEnd of for loop write final result\n.");

    i = j = 0;

    while (s1[i] != '\0'){
        printf("final is :%c ", s1[i]);
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this code suppose to  remove one letter at the beginning letter 'a' in my example and then, the while loop will go thru each position to print the result.

it looks like the first part is working, but the while loop is never executed by the program.

any ideas why ?

Thank you

Comment: Well then, your loop condition evaluates to false.  So time to lean how to use a debugger and examine the variables.

Comment: The null character indicates the string ends at that position, not that it should be considered as skipping a character. I'm not sure if your code is assuming that or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't demonstrate any debugging attempts.

Comment: Change `s1[i] = s1[i]` to whatever it is you wanted to do (probably `s1[i] = s2[i]` or something)

Comment: Yep, you should definitely try to debug your code (printf usually is enough) before asking if you really want to learn. Anyway, just to help you, i indented your code in a much clearer way (regardless of the algorithm) http://paste.ubuntu.com/6822705/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute this

```
s1[i] = '\0';
```

when i = 0, so the while condition

```
while (s1[i] != '\0') { ...
```

is false and you never execute the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of the for loop, you assign `'\0'` to `s[0]`:

```
// s1[0] is 'a', s2[0] is 'a'
if (s1[i] == s2[j]){
    printf("before %c\n", s1[i]);
    s1[i] = '\0';
}
```

And so it stays ( as `i` and `j` are both incremented ). When you get to the `while` loop, `s[0]` is still `'\0'`, so it doesn't execute even once.

Comment: Thank you so much for that prompt answer.I totally understand i just need to copy the i+1 value instead of the '\0' value.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (s1[i] == s2[j]){
    printf("before %c\n", s1[i]);
    s1[i] = '\0';

}
```

to

```
if (s1[i] == s2[j]){
    printf("before %c\n", s1[i]);
    s1[i] = ' ';  
}
```

for your `while` loop to work.